# need to print post filtered by my current taxonomy's page?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, custom-taxonomy

i need to print all my post filtered by my current taxonomy's page.
which is the query with which I can have all these posts filtered for the current page taxonomy?
i'm trying to do a widget dynamic to use into more pages with different categories.
i hope someone can help me . thx :)
i'm trying with this code but doesn't work...

```
 <?php
$args=array(
  'post_type' => 'post,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
    <?php
  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved:

```
<?php

 $term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
 $taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );

  $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array (
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomyName,
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $term_slug,
          )
        ),
      ));
  ?>
```